# Sybase create function (Exercise)

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

The main task sounds like this: "Make the function of combining the name and surname so that it matches the official style ("**surname, firstname**") f_name(**firstname, secondname**). If I correctly understood the task, then when entering ("**First Name**", "**Last Name**"), then at the output it should change their places -->("**Last Name", "First Name**").

I apologize if this sound clumsy, I study in another language. It should be simple, but I don’t know how to implement it.

This is what i have at this moment.

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_name ( Surname VARCHAR(50), Firstname VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
BEGIN
DECLARE official VARCHAR(200);
SET official = Surname + Firstname;
RETURN official 
END;

SELECT f_name('Marko', 'Polo') as official ;
```

Comment: what is your code returning? what are you expecting the code to return (for 'Marko'/'Polo')?